# Is there something one has to do to get chrome window.navigator.serial `requestPort` working in Production on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vuejs2, serial-port

Simply put, Web Serial is working locally in development, however, when I deploy my VueJS app to Production (a static site hosted on AWS S3) `window.navigator.serial.requestPort({})` fails. The [Experimental Web Platform Features](http://chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features) is enabled...

error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestPort' of undefined
at a.connect (home.vue:111)
at ne (vue.runtime.esm.js:1854)
at HTMLButtonElement.n (vue.runtime.esm.js:2175)
at HTMLButtonElement.Ji.o._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js:6911)
ie @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1888
```

I thought it could be an S3 permissions thing, but I can't find another relative permission to unlock...

Any help would be appreciated... Google is not my friend today... Thank you!!

Comment: S3 just serves the raw javascript files to the web browser. Your code is running entirely inside the web browser. I don't see how S3 could be causing this error at all.

Comment: me either. This is why I posted the question... I'm stumped: could it have something to do with the difference between `npm run build` and `npm run serve` ?

Comment: Yes I suspect it has to do with the some difference in the compiled and bundled code, versus the code you are testing locally.

Comment: How would I fix that

Comment: have you found a fix? same problem here, windows.navigator.serial doesn't exist when serving from s3 bucket